# How to run multiple combinations of groups in a single TestNG test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I need to execute all 3 classes in single test with following requirements:

1. Execute only test1 and test3 from Class1.
2. Execute only test2 from Class2.
3. Execute all tests from Class3.

   ```
   public class Class1
   {
   @Test(groups={"test1"})
   public void test1()
   {
   system.out.println("test1");
   }
   @Test(groups={"test2"})
   public void test2()
   {
   system.out.println("test2");
   }
   @Test(groups={"test3"})
   public void test3()
   {
   system.out.println("test3");
   }
   }
   ```

Class 2

```
    public class Class2
    {
    @Test(groups={"test1"})
    public void test_1()
    {
    system.out.println("test1");
    }
    @Test(groups={"test2"})
    public void test_2()
    {
    system.out.println("test2");
    }
    @Test(groups={"test3"})
    public void test_3()
    {
    system.out.println("test3");
    }
    }
```

Class 3

```
    public class Class3
    {
    @Test(alwaysrun="true")
    public void test()
    {
    system.out.println("test");
    }
    }
```

For this I used following testNg xml but all the tests in Class 1 and Class 3 are executed irrespective of whether I included the group or not.

```
    <test name="Testcase">
    <classes>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="test1" />
                <exclude name="test2" />
                <include name="test3" />
                    <class name="Class1" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="test1" />
                <include name="test2" />
                <exclude name="test3" />
                    <class name="Class2" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <groups>
            <run>
            </run>
            <class name="Class3" />
        </groups>       
    </classes>
    </test>
```

Please suggest what should be the correct syntax of TestNg xml file if I wish execute class files as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML file contains the problem: `class` should not be part of `groups` and groups is not part of `classes`.

Also your code has compilation issues. The simplest solution would be to annotate the test or test class (you can annotate the whole class as Test and provide a group name) and then run only that specific group.

Example:

**Class 1**

```
public class Class1
{
    @Test(groups={"smoke"})
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test(groups={"func"})
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("test2");
    }

    @Test(groups={"smoke"})
    public void test3(){
        System.out.println("test3");
    }
}
```

**Class 2**

```
public class Class2
{
    @Test(groups={"func"})
    public void test_1(){
        System.out.println("test1");
    }
    @Test(groups={"smoke"})
    public void test_2(){
        System.out.println("test2");
    }
    @Test(groups={"func"})
    public void test_3(){
        System.out.println("test3");
    }
}
```

**Class 3**

```
@Test(groups = {"smoke"})
public class Class3
{
    @Test(alwaysRun=true)
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<suite name="Regression" >

<test name="Test1">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="smoke"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="Class1"/>
        <class name="Class2"/>
        <class name="Class3"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but as suggested by you I'll have to change my class file every time if I need to execute a different combination of test from both classes. I wish to create a test suite in which I can run any combination of tests. That's why I gave a unique group name to each test. Is it possible?

Comment: if you give unique group name to each test, it's not an group by definition. you could just `include` or `exclude` methods in `testng.xml` file. 
https://www.google.pl/search?safe=active&q=group+definition&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW07uFv5DXAhUKS5oKHSzAAsAQvwUIJSgA&biw=1920&bih=903

Comment: But in case, I require a different combination of tests to be run, I would have to make changes in my class file. That is why I wanted to find a solution to control it from xml itself. Could you suggest if these is any possibility?

Comment: yes. use test methods and class in xml rather than groups. check the testng documention.